# Work done by a component of a force

Tags: forces, work, mathematics

I'm readyng a textbook of intuitive calculus that uses physics in several exercises. The next exercise is found in a section that explains how to use the chain rule of derivation to integrate functions by substitution.

[image: 1]

I have no problem with the provided suggestion and the answer, but when I tried a pure mathematical approach, by using the chain rule, I stated that $$\frac{dW}{dx}= \frac{dW}{dr} \cdot \frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{k}{r^2} \left(-\frac{c-x}{\sqrt{p^2+(c-x)^2}}\right) = -\frac{k(c-x)}{r^3}$$ which has the opposite sign of the other approach and leads to the result $\frac{k}{a}-\frac{k}{b}$ that makes no physical sense because the component of the force has the same direction of the movement, so the work done by the force must be positive. I'm not sure where is the problem, since as $x$ increases, $r$ decreases; so the derivative $\frac{dr}{dx}$ must be negative and because $\frac{dW}{dx}$ is positive, $\frac{dW}{dr}=F(r)$ has to be negative, right? But I can't see why the force is negative, or maybe the force $F(r)$ can't be viewed as the derivative of work respect to $r$ because there's no movement in the line that connects the particle to the point *O*.

Comment: You have my sympathies.  This is definitely physics according to a mathematician, and it will tend to convince you that physics is math, which it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{dW}{dr}$ is negative. This can be easily checked, because You got positive work done when $r$ decrease. However, you got a positive $\frac{dW}{dr}=\frac{k}{r^2}$ which must be wrong.